# How to prettify components bootstrapped with Gatsby on save in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, visual-studio-code, gatsby, prettier

I'm trying to enable formatting on save in VSCode in a Gatsby project, per the Gatsby docs: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-zero/#install-the-prettier-plugin

I also tried setting up eslint so now I have:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": { "prettier/prettier": "error" },
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  "settings": {
    "import/core-modules": ["react"]
  }
}
```

in my .eslintrc.json and

```
{
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5"
}
```

in my .prettierrc.

I have Format on save, on paste, and on type enabled in both my User Settings and my Workspace settings and it appears to work in my .eslintrc.json and in a .css file, but not with the Gatsby components (Header.js, Layout.js, etc). I can format these component files by opening the command palette and manually clicking 'Format Document,' but not automatically on save.